# Is there a way to remove the .html extensions in Hosting Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

I found in the firebase documents that you could hide the .html extensions of my site by creating a "firebase.json" file. I effectively remove the extensions but when I want to enter my other pages I cannot. I always see the main page.

I tried previously with .htaccess but it didn't work out. Now I found this firebase resource but any extension directs me to the main page.

I put that in my file "firebase.json"

```
"hosting": {

  "cleanUrls": true,
  "trailingSlash": false
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set up routes inside of `firebase.json`. They can either be `rewrites` (where the URL is actually pointing to another location, but that is unknown to the user), or `redirects` (where the page redirects to another URL).

Inside of your `firebase.json`, `hosting` should look like this:

```json
"hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/sign-up",
            "destination": "/sign-up.html"
        }
    ],
    "redirects": [
        {
            "source": "/sign-up.html",
            "destination": "/sign-up"
        }
    ]
}
```

There are 2 added nodes, `rewrites`, and `redirects`. What this does is whenever someone visits `/sign-up`, you actually point them to `/sign-up.html`, where your actual HTML code is. But when someone visits `/sign-up.html` on their own, you redirect them to `/sign-up`.

Comment: `"hosting": {

  "cleanUrls": true,
  "trailingSlash": false,

  "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
        {
            "source": "/proyectos",
            "destination": "/proyectos.html"
        }
    ],
    "redirects": [
        {
            "source": "/proyectos.html",
            "destination": "/proyectos"
        }
       
    ]
}`

That is my code of `firebase.json` you can see my page in [link](xmobiliario.com)
It was not fixed

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache of your browser? On chrome macOS, press Cmd+y and on the left click "Clear browsing data" and only select clear cache.