# How to remove .html URL endings and configure redirects in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, url, redirect, firebase-hosting

Edit: Fixed an mistake in which I referred to `about.html` as `/about/` in my HTML, but am still experiencing the same issues.

---

I understand that this is a duplicate of a question that has been asked many times before, but the solutions of others are not working for me. What I'm trying to do is reroute, for example, `index.html` to `/index/` and `about.html` to `/about/`.

I tried to use @louisvno's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44173400/firebase-hosting-url-needs-html-to-display-a-page), @michael-bleigh's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60681599/remove-file-extensions-for-html-files-in-firebase), and @HarsH's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730092/how-to-remove-html-from-url), all of which were to add the following to the .json file:

```
"hosting": {
    "cleanUrls": true
  }
```

(*This is also the answer on Firebase's "[Control .html extensions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#control_html_extensions)" section of their guide to configuring hosting behavior.*)

However, this had no effect. In my HTML file, I tried setting the `<a>` tags to `href="index.html`, `href="/index/`, and `href="/index"`, but none of these options worked and I'm not really sure if changing it from the original `<a href="index.html">` was even necessary. (Is it?)

The other solution I tried was to utilize the `"redirects"` property, as suggested by @ken-mueller [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57332661/is-there-a-way-to-remove-the-html-extensions-in-hosting-firebase). I removed the "clearUrls" bit and put the following in my .json file:

```
  "hosting": {
    "redirects": [ {
      "source": "index.html",
      "destination": "/index",
      "type": 301
    }, {
      "source": "index.html{,/**}",
      "destination": "/index",
      "type": 3011
    }, {
      "source": "about.html",
      "destination": "/calculator",
      "type": 301
    }, {
      "source": "about.html{,/**}",
      "destination": "/solutions",
      "type": 301
    } ]
  }
```

(*This is also the answer on Firebase's [Configure redirects section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#redirects) of their guide to configuring hosting behavior*)

This, too, had no effect. And, even when changing my HTML from `<a href="about.html">` to `<a href="/about/">` or `<a href="/about">`, it just broke the `about.html` page and displayed the `index.html` page instead.

What am I doing wrong? How can I remove the .html from the end of the URL and make sure that any time it is input in the URL, it redirects to the URL without the ending (i.e. `/index/` instead of `/index.html`?

Comment: Setting `"cleanUrls": true` in the firebase.json file allows you to leave the `.html` off the files, so `/index.html` becomes `/index` (no trailing `/`). If that's not working for you, can you point us to a URL where you configured this?

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm hosting this on carbonfootprint.dev. Still not working for some reason.

Comment: The clean URLs work for me, e.g.: https://carbonfootprint.dev/calculator. But from reading the documentation it seems hosting should also auto-rewrite `https://carbonfootprint.dev/calculator.html` to `https://carbonfootprint.dev/calculator`, which does not seem to happen. You might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: The clean URL actually linked to the wrong page, `/calculator` should link to `calculator.html` but for some reason it displays the index. Does this mean anything?

Comment: Hmmm... that sounds like you have a [rewrite](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites) that overrides the clean URL redirects. I'm actually not sure how the combination of those flags is supposed to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the issue thanks to Mau from Firebase Support. `"cleanUrls"` works fine, I just needed an opening and closing bracket (duh). For the code in my post, I also noticed one of the redirects had `"type":` set to `3011` instead of `301`. Either way, the final code is:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "cleanUrls": true,
    "trailingSlash": true
  }
}
```